# Using System.Web.Http on mac os x

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, dnx, dnvm

I'm new to mac but not .Net. I'm playing around with Visual Studio Code. I installed Brew and used it to get `yo`, `grunt-cli`, `generator-aspnet`, `dnvm`, and everything the tutorials say to get. I created a project scaffold with `yo` and the first thing I want to do is add a Controller that inherits from [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) but I can't seem to find a way to "Add a reference" like I would in Visual Studio proper.

It looks like I should open project.json and add something like this:

```
"System.Web.Http": "<some version number>"
```

under dependencies. I don't know what version number to use, so I tried "latest" but anytime I run `dnu update` it says System.Web.Http can't be found.

Where can I find information about adding references to Visual Studio Code? How to reference particular DLLs (specifically `System.Web.Http` for me) and what versions to reference?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track, but `System.Web.Http` isn't a .Net Core library. A sample MVC project is https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/samples/MvcSample.Web - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question has several parts.

### ApiController

First of all, ASP.NET MVC 6 unifies WebAPI and MVC 5 controllers into one. You can still use ApiController if you want to, but you will need `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim`.

### There is no System.Web.Net

Second, [Matt DeKrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743919/using-system-web-http-on-mac-os-x#comment49548355_30743919) is correct. `System.Web.Http` is not a .NET core library. Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be looking for `System.Web.Http.Common`.

### Finding package version

When using VS Code, you should be seeing autocomplete that will recommend version numbers for you. In this case you could use:

```
"System.Web.Http.Common": "4.0.20216.16343"
```

[image: screen shot of autocomplete version numbers]